# Post new comment to facebook comments using fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-comments

I have successfully retrieved the comments on a specific link using the fql with the following code:

```
{\"comments\":\"SELECT fromid, text, time, comments FROM comment WHERE object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url ='http://permalink')\", \"users\":\"SELECT name, id FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT fromid FROM #comments)\"}
```

I want to post new comment and I have the access token of the user, what is the right way to do this using fql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware,you can't insert using FQL. FQL is merely a query language used to perform more complex queries than the Graph API endpoints offer allowing you to perform joins etc (Not joins in the traditional sense but using "IN" statements).

You would need to use the graph api and issue a POST request as detailed towards the bottom of this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/